# Android location stops updating location after some time

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have an app, which main feature is to track user's workouts. GPS location was working OK for past few years until this month, when strange issue appeared.

Some people (not all), using different devices and android versions experience strange behaviour of gps location. Suddenly, after at least few minutes (sometimes few hours) onLocationChanged stops being fired. Sometimes it's working fine, then next day user has this issue again.

User has to start a new workout to get it back to work. Also, in the app logs I found out that

`onConnectionSuspended`

is called with cause = 1 (CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED).

According to the documentation, lost connection should automatically reconnect, but it doesn't thus causing the described issue.

In order to fix that issue, I've created an internal timer (runnable), which checks when was the last time that location was updated. If it's more than, let's say, 2 minutes, it reconnects everything like this:

```
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
startLocationUpdates(); //calls requestLocationUpdates
```

It seems to be working, at least on one's of our test user devices. Seems like a small hack to me, so let me ask you: have you experienced similar issue and do you have a better way to solve it?

By the way, I'm using:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

only thing I can think of is to restart gps receiver after not getting location for some time / start vibrating phone so user know and can restart his phone / try to register more providers not only gms. Try fused, classic GPS/network location listener.. if all of them send broadcast to some class and that class wait few seconds then prioritize the best one of those you got in time it would be great! I tried this, it worked but i need to have accuracy like 3 meters.. :D so not possible for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: + I dont know direct answer too but better than no answer. I just think this could help